# Invalid XML comes out as valid

Tags: c#, xml, validation

I have made an XML schema to validate incoming xml files to validate if they are an Error or not.
I have some code that should return true when an xml file is valid, or false when it's not.
I have also made two XML files, one of which is valid, the other invalid. However, my code returns true for both of them, aka considers them both valid. How come? Where did I go wrong?

The schema:
**XMLSchemaError.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="XMLSchemaError"
    targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchemaError.xsd"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchemaError.xsd"
    xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchemaError.xsd"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>
  <xs:element name="Error">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Server_ID" type="xs:integer" />
        <xs:element name="Prioritizing" type="xs:token" />
        <xs:element name="Type" type="xs:token" />
        <xs:element name="Thrown_by" type="xs:token" />
        <xs:element name="Code" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="Text" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="Time_occured" type="xs:dateTime" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Code to validate the XML file:
**XMLValidation.cs**

```
private bool isValid = false;       

public bool checkValid(string fileName)
{
    try
    {
        var reader = XmlReader.Create("../../XMLFiles/" + fileName);
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
        doc.Load(reader);
        doc.Schemas.Add(null, "../../Model/XMLSchemaError.xsd");
        doc.Validate(ValidationCallBack);
        isValid = true;
    }
    catch
    {
        isValid = false;
    }            
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Check: " + isValid);
    return isValid;
}

private void ValidationCallBack(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
{
    throw new Exception();
}
```

The 2 XML files to validate:
**Valid.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
    <Server_ID>4</Server_ID>
    <Prioritizing>major</Prioritizing>
    <Type>test error</Type>
    <Thrown_by>test program</Thrown_by>
    <Code></Code>
    <Text></Text>
    <Time_occurred>2016-02-9T12:34:56.7890</Time_occurred>
</Error>
```

**Invalid.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Comment: Your schema describes elements in the `http://tempuri.org/XMLSchemaError.xsd`. Neither of your pieces of XML claim to be in any namespace (i.e. neither uses any `xmlns` attributes)

Comment: Okay. I'm pretty new to XML, so could you tell me how I add that namespace attribute to the XML file to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commenter [Damien_The_Unbeliever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35412139/invalid-xml-comes-out-as-valid#comment58525364_35412139) points out, since your XML doesn't claim to contain any elements that are validated by the schema in question, both documents trivially pass validation. There's nothing in them to validate.

There are a variety of ways to correct the situation. The simplest is to just add a default XML namespace to the root element. E.g.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchemaError.xsd">
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Having done that, the above XML now will fail validation according to your schema.

If you were to do the same thing to the "valid" XML, you would find that it too fails validation. This is for two reasons:

1. The schema misspells the word "occurred", while the XML does not. This can be fixed either by correcting the spelling the schema or by using the misspelling in the XML.
2. The XML has an incorrectly formatted `dateTime` value. The day-of-month field is specified using only a single digit, but the XML format requires two digits for both the month and day-of-month fields.

An actual valid XML, given the schema you've provided, would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchemaError.xsd">
    <Server_ID>4</Server_ID>
    <Prioritizing>major</Prioritizing>
    <Type>test error</Type>
    <Thrown_by>test program</Thrown_by>
    <Code></Code>
    <Text></Text>
    <Time_occured>2016-02-09T12:34:56.7890</Time_occured>
</Error>
```

(I've opted to misspell the element name in the XML, rather than fixing the schema, just because it simplifies the example XML required in this answer :) ).

Comment: Thanks, not only did this fix the problem but I understand now what I did wrong :)